# Is there a way to make context-sensitive autocomplete for C++ in VIM?

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete, intellisense

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Autocompletion in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115876/autocompletion-in-vim)
>   [Vim, Python, and Django autocompletion (pysmell?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978643/vim-python-and-django-autocompletion-pysmell)

I don't know if that's the right word for it. When I use Ctrl+n in VIM to use autocomplete it doesn't do a very smart job of suggesting member functions or variables or what-have-you. Visual studio's intellisense makes suggestions that make more sense given the context (or if you're really spoiled, you might even have Visual Assist X to help you out). Is there similar functionality for VIM, or am I stuck with the regular Ctrl+n?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115876/autocompletion-in-vim

Comment: Sorry, for some reason that question didn't pop up in the suggested results when I was typing it.