# Vim and python: context-unaware autocompletion of language methods

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, omnicomplete

I am writing a little python script to learn VIM basics (I'm a beginner with VIM).
I've configured VIM to work with omnicompletion, and it does.
For example, if I write str. then press ctr+x, ctr+o it suggests me all of the string methods.
However in my code I have something like this:

```
for line in inFile.readlines():
    something = line.rpartition(" ")[0]
```

I'd like VIM to autocomplete the rpartition method name after typing line.rpart. I don't expect it to know line object type, but I'd like VIM to propose a context-unaware completion list based on python libraries acquaintance.
For example if with eclipse i try to complete

```
anObject.rpart
```

it suggests me the rpartition method even if it has nothing to do with anObject!

Is it possible to get this to work with VIM?
Thanks.

My .vimrc file:

```
set showcmd
set textwidth=80
set expandtab
set smarttab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set number
set autoindent
filetype indent on
filetype plugin on
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py syntax on
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set ai
autocmd BufRead *.py set smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,with,try,except,finally,def,class
set modeline
syntax on
" Closes the Omni-Completion tip window when a selection is
" made
autocmd CursorMovedI * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
autocmd InsertLeave * if pumvisible() == 0|pclose|endif
```

Comment: Use `for line in file`. The `.readlines()` jsut sluprs the whole file into memory at once, needlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should take a look at [PySmell](http://code.google.com/p/pysmell/) which can be installed for Vim easily. It generates a completion menu based on a static analysis for a given project. It also can generate completion suggestions based on tags it produces for external libraries like the Python Standard Library or Django Lib.

I was happy with Vims Python omnicimpletion, but since I switched to PySmell, I never looked back.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I understand, pySmell gives what omnicompletion gives, plus extra features?

Comment: Absolutely, but it operates only for Python. Omnicompletion operates for more programming languages. You can use Pysmell for Python and Omnicompletion for other programming languages in the same Vim instance.

Comment: Thanks again, another question: when the code changes (e.g., new class added), you have to update the PYSMELLTAGS file I guess?

Comment: As I know the answer is YES. I suggest you to have a  look at this thread at SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978643/vim-python-and-django-autocompletion-pysmell) and this link (http://www.sontek.net/topic/vim) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously, use [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim)!

It's really much better than all the other autocompletions around.

May the force be with you!