# How to enable full autocomplete with vim and django?

Tags: python, django, vim, autocomplete

I am new with python and vim. Now I am trying enable  autocomplete for django's metaclasses.
So, I have autocomplete most common django classes, but when I tried get autocomplete for django's metaclass, for example model class

```
Fruits.objects.all()
```

I failed.
Now I use simple omnicompletion, because YouCompleteMe plugin doesnot work with python3, and jedi-vim doesnt work with vim without +python flag. Is any way to make this with omnicompletion?

Comment: Have you tried pycharm? It's quite easy to use and it has autocomplete

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978643/vim-python-and-django-autocompletion-pysmell

Comment: @HoapHumanoid yes, but now I developing on remote server, where is no X. So. no pycharm, no atom, sublime does not fit too.

Comment: @RoshanJossey thanks, but jedi-vim doesnot understand metaclass too.
https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/298