# How to setup Pysmell using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner with python :(

I already installed Python3 and I need to do the below items

1. I'm trying to run `Pysmell` using python.
2. Run `Pysmell` on any random Python project from GitHub.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978643/vim-python-and-django-autocompletion-pysmell

Checkout this link, maybe it's help you out.

Comment: Yes, I check it out but I don't understand.