# How do I get omnicompletion for Python external libraries?

Tags: python, vim

I've setup my gVim to have omnicompletion, but only for the standard library atm.. How do I include other libraries (Django, Pygame, etc...)?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you set up the omnicompletion in the standard library? If you post the description it might be possible to extend.

Comment: Also found this duplicate of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199180/is-there-any-way-to-get-python-omnicomplete-to-work-with-non-system-modules-in-vi

Comment: I did it by putting this line in my _vimrc ":filetype plugin indent on"

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tutorial on using omnicomplete with Django](http://blog.fluther.com/blog/2008/10/17/django-vim/).

Comment: I've read that tutorial, but I never got it to work and I got stuck on this part: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_FILE=myapp.settings vim'. 
And when I was asking around #vim on IRC, someone told my that putting lines like these - 'autocmd FileType python set omnifunc=pythoncomplete#Complete' - is not a good idea, it's outdated or something.. He helped me out, and I got omnicompletion for the standard library.  So, now I'm really confused on what I should follow.

Comment: I read that tutorial also.  It also did not work for me. But, how did you get omnicompletion for the std library?